# Manipulating data in database by passing IDs of check-boxes checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm setting an asp.net web app project. Getting down to the problem now:
(I'm new to Ajax, JQuery and Asp.net)

1) I found a way to store the IDs of checked boxes in a string "CommaSeparatedIDs" - in Index.cshtml file (SaveFinished() function)

2) Defining the "SaveFinished()" function in "Index.cshtml.cs". I don't know how to define the function/where to define it in the file. Purpose of the function: Has a string parameter defined in 1), which manipulates database using the IDs.

3) Lastly, my implementation of "SaveFinished()" might have errors which I'm not able to point out.

I tried defining the function "SaveFinished()" in different regions of "Index.cshtml.cs" and the function never got recognized or referenced, I don't know what should be the type of the function as well.

Index.cshtml:

```
<table class="table" id="MainTable">  // (Table used to define the various entries)
...
...
   <th>
      <a class="btn btn-success" onclick=SaveFinished()>Done</a> // JS function SaveFinished()
   </th>
...
...
    @foreach (var item in Model.ExcelData) // ExcelData is the object defined in Index.cshtml.cs (given below)

        <tr>
           <td>
               <input id="@item.ID" type="checkbox" />
           </td>
        ...
        ...
       </tr>
// I think I have errors below which I can't figure out.
<script>

    var SaveFinished = function () {
        var ArrItem = [];
        var CommaSeparatedIDs = "";

        $("MainTable tbody tr input[type=checkbox] ").each(function () {
            debugger
            var checkId = $(val).attr("id");
            var IsChecked = $("#" + checkId).is(":checked", true);
            if (IsChecked) {
                ArrItem.push(checkId);
            }
        })
        if (ArrItem.length != 0) {
            CommaSeparatedIDs = ArrItem.toString();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Excel_Data/Index", <!--This should be the URL of the page?-->
                type: "POST",
                data: { MainTable: CommaSeparatedIDs },
                success: function (response) {
                     <!-- What should I do here? I'm new to Ajax and JQuery -->
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
namespace Customer.Pages.Excel_Data
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Customer.Models.CustomerContext _context;
        public IndexModel(Customer.Models.CustomerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        #region Variables

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
         #region Data manipulation and setting variables      
        } 
    }
}
```

My expected result is to pass the string "CommaSeparatedIDs" in "SaveFinished()" function to the logic part of the page - "Index.cshtml.cs" and manipulate the database.

Comment: What is the definition of your model and the post handler in Index.cshtml.cs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear about the definition of your model and the post handler , the following is the worked example , you could refer to

Model

```
public class ExcelData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorPages2_1Project.Data.RazorPagesDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(RazorPages2_1Project.Data.RazorPagesDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<ExcelData> ExcelData { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        ExcelData = await _context.ExcelData.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody]string CommaSeparatedIDs)
    {
       //stuff you want
    }
}
```

Your project is a Razor Pages . **Razor Pages** are designed to be automatically protected from **cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF)** attacks. You don’t have to write any additional code. Antiforgery token generation and validation is automatically included in Razor Pages. If 400 bad request error occurs, there is no AntiForgeryToken present on the page. Add explicitly using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`like below :

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table class="table" id="MainTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExcelData[0].Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="SaveFinished()">Done</a>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ExcelData)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="@item.ID" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    function SaveFinished() {
        var ArrItem = [];
        var CommaSeparatedIDs = "";

        $("#MainTable tbody tr input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
           // debugger;
            var checkId = $(this).attr("id");
            var IsChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
            if (IsChecked) {
                ArrItem.push(checkId);
            }
        });
        if (ArrItem.length != 0) {
            CommaSeparatedIDs = ArrItem.toString();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Excel_Data/Index",
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(CommaSeparatedIDs),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

Since the script sends the token in a header called **XSRF-TOKEN**, configure the antiforgery service to look for the **XSRF-TOKEN** header:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
}
```

Reference :

[Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply! Your definition of the model and post handler are close enough and serve the purpose. However, the OnPostAsync threw an error and had to change it to public void OnPostAsync(). I haven't gone ahead in this direction further cause have to work on some other part of the project! Thanks for the help, appreciate it :)